# ios 7 subviews UINavigatoinBar overlapping with statusbar..Any simple solution..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

For ioS 7 project, where I am not using storyboard,if we put UINavigationbar on subviews it is overlapping with statusbar. samething is working fine upto ios6.1 so what is best way to solve this so that it looks same as ios6.1. I have tried 64px image for UInavigationbar and shifting bar 20 px down for ios7 with 44px image, there is any other way which requires less effort and work like charm...

Answer (score 0):

You need add the This in your `-(void)viewDidLoad` method.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```